# ¿Por qué HTML acepta como color una cadena arbitraria?

Tags: html

Al correr una página y ponerle en el valor del color de fondo una cadena arbitraria como por ejemplo `"chucknorris"` el fondo se pone rojo. ¿Por qué sucede esto?

```html
<body bgcolor="chucknorris">test</body>
```

---

Pregunta original: [Why does HTML think “chucknorris” is a color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318911/why-does-html-think-chucknorris-is-a-color)

Comment: ¿Es en serio? Bueno, se me ocurre que ellos tambien tienen sentido del humor y esto es algún tipo de Easter Egg

Comment: Claro que es en serio... ¡si tan solo tuviera padrinos mágicos! digo... si tan solo tuviera `stack snippets`

Comment: Efectivamente dicen que es un Easter Egg, pero es curioso que soporten muchas palabras distintas como colores he probado con "Underline" que devolvía un verde si bien recuerdo y ni idea de por que.

Comment: también he oido que se pone rojo debido a la sangre de sus enemigos... pero no sé si creerlo :P

Comment: jeje, al parecer es por combinación de caracteres estos dan hexadecimales que cumplen con el color rojo.

Comment: pues yo la traduzco...

Comment: @Elenasys creo que acaban de traducirla

Comment: en la respuesta que indica @AngelAngel hay ejemplos de varias  palabras y de como las trata html.

Comment: Curioso, esto no lo sabía, pero puede ser tan útil como divertido.

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318911/why-does-html-think-chucknorris-is-a-color

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Referencia: [Why does HTML think “chucknorris” is a color?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8318911/3160466)

Si tienes caracteres inválidos en un código de color que está escrito en notación hexadecimal, estos caracteres son tratadas como 0. Un número hexadecimal puede contener las caracteres `[0-9a-f]`, cualquier otro carácter encontrado es reemplazado con `0`.

Para `chucknorris`:

- Reemplazar caracteres inválidos:
  `chucknorris` → `c00c0000000`
- Rellenar con `0` hasta que el número de caracteres es divisible por 3:
  `c00c0000000` (11) → `c00c 0000 0000` (12)
- Formatear en notación RGB:
  `rgb(c00c, 0000, 0000)`
- Truncar cada valor a dos caracteres:
  `rgb(c0, 00, 00)`
- Traducir de hexadecimal a decimal:
  `rgb(192, 0, 0)   [ == #C00000]`

El color resultante: rojo.

Otros colores similares: `crap`, `ninjaturtle`, `sick`, `grass`.

Comment: Parece una traducción hecha con alguna herramienta, puedes mejorarla ? La frase "Caracteres inválidos en códigos de color HEX son igual de cero" es confusa.

Comment: @Zero no con una herramienta, solo mi español mal. Quiero decir que si tienes caracteres inválidos en un código de color que es escrito en notación HEX, estos caracteres son tratadas como 0.

Answer (score 17):

Es un vestigio de los días de Netscape:

> Los dígitos faltantes se tratan como 0 [...]. Un dígito incorrecto
>   simplemente se interpreta como 0. Por ejemplo los valores # f0f0f0,
>   f0f0f0, F0F0F, #FxFxFx y FxFxFx son todos iguales.

A partir de esta entrada del [blog](http://scrappy-do.blogspot.mx/2004/08/little-rant-about-microsoft-internet.html), que cubre en gran detalle, incluyendo diferentes longitudes de valores de color, etc.

Si aplicamos las reglas mencionadas en la entrada del blog, obtenemos lo siguiente:

Reemplazar todos los caracteres hexadecimales no válidos con 0's

```
ChuckNorris se convierte a c00c0000000
```

Se rellena el siguiente número total de caracteres divisibles por 3 (11 -> 12)

```
c00c 0.000 0.000
```

Dividir en tres grupos iguales, con cada componente que representa el componente de color correspondiente de un color RGB:

```
RGB (c00c, 0000, 0000)
```

Truncar cada uno de los argumentos desde la derecha a 2 caracteres

Obtenemos el siguiente resultado:

```
RGB (c0, 00, 00) = # C00000 o RGB (192, 0, 0)
```

He aquí un ejemplo que demuestra el atributo bgcolor en acción, para producir esta "increíble" muestra de color:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="chucknorris" cellpadding="8" width="100" align="center">chuck norris</td>
    <td bgcolor="mrt" cellpadding="8" width="100" align="center" style="color:#ffffff">Mr T</td>
    <td bgcolor="ninjaturtle" cellpadding="8" width="100" align="center" style="color:#ffffff">ninjaturtle</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="sick" cellpadding="8" width="100" align="center">sick</td>
    <td bgcolor="crap" cellpadding="8" width="100" align="center">crap</td>
    <td bgcolor="grass" cellpadding="8" width="100" align="center">grass</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Esto también responde a la otra parte de la pregunta; ¿por qué bgcolor = "chucknorr" produce un color amarillo? Bueno, si aplicamos las reglas, el valor del string es:

```
c00c00000 => c00 c00 000 => c0 c0 00 [RGB (192, 192, 0)]
```

Lo que da un color amarillo oro claro. Como la cadena inicia con 9 caracteres, mantenemos la segunda C en esta ocasión, por tanto termina en el valor final de color.

Originalmente me encontré con esto cuando alguien señaló que podría hacer color="basura" y, bueno, se obtiene el color cafe.

de la respuesta original de [@dash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8333464/250260) en SOen.

Comment: Buena y amplia explicación

Comment: Increible que bgcolor funcione también en tablas en navegadores actuales

Comment: jeje, Mis antepasados tuvieron sus inicios en desarrollo web, actualmente es desarrollo para aplicaciones de escritorio ó móviles =)

Comment: Esta es la respuesta mas completa.

Comment: lo malo es que en ningun momento menciona al autor original del comentario  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318911/why-does-html-think-chucknorris-is-a-color

Comment: @marcogomes hola Marco, generalmente se hace referencia a una respuesta si es que es una copia (o traducción) de la misma, la referencia a la pregunta ya la agrego Ruslan a la pregunta de este thread.

Comment: Generalmente pero en tu caso hay que recordartelo, si no lo hubieras hecho hace 2 anos y no ahora que yo lo menciono :)

Comment: Pues te agradezco me lo recuerdes, tengo 1,968 respuestas, es difícil seguir la pista de una respuesta cuando ocurrió hace tiempo =/. Por cierto veo que vives en Londres, pero eres de Aragua, Venezuela?